# How can I neatly print a timeline with events?

Tags: prolog

Our assignment is to display a timeline of events in Prolog.
Our database looks something like this:

```
event(e1, 20).  
event(e2, before(e1)).  
event(e3, before(e2)).  
event(e4, 15).  
event(e5, before(5)).  
event(e6, 30).  
event(e7, before(e2)).
```

Our idea is to define 2 points (0 and nil) as fixed values, and represent the timelines like this:

```
0   5   15  20  30          nil  
\ x x e4    e1  e6  /  
\ e5/             
\ x e3  e2      /     
\ x e7  /
```

(Sorry, I don't know how tabs work here, and I can't post a screenshot)

Our idea is to find all possible paths from 0 to nil, and try to see which nodes can be merged.

The paths would look something like this:

```
[  
[0, e4, e1, e6, nil],  
[0, e5, e4, e1, e6, nil],  
[0, e3, e2, e1, e6, nil],  
[0, e7, e2, e1, e6, nil]  
]
```

How can we find the events in the correct order? It seems we can't work our way forward from 0, because to find the first event, you have to make sure it's before some other event or something?

Comment: @Paul: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @Highi, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Comment: 39 questions have been tagged homework in the last week. Not all by me :) So discouraged it may be by some, but it's also commonly used. I (like others, it seems to me) will still use it for questions that smell like homework but don't admit to it in the question

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make this clear, but yes, it's homework. I don't expect anyone to just "giv mah teh codez", but I'm actually trying to learn something here. I know my question was maybe a bit vague, so I will rephrase it.

Answer (score 0):

Are the time slots multiple of 5? Implies a before() that the
event is placed in the next time slot? Does an event only have
one event fact? Then you could try something as follows.

Define a predicate eff_time_slot(Event, Time). It will
be recursively defined as follows:

```
   eff_time_slot(Event,Time) :- event(Event,Expr), eval_time_expr(Expr,Time).

   eval_time_expr(Num,Num) :- number(Num), !.
   eval_time_expr(before(Expr),Num) :- !, eval_time_expr(Expr,Help), Num is Help+5.
   eval_time_expr(Event,Num) :- eff_time_slot(Event,Num).
```

If an event can have multiple event facts, then you have to
modify the predicate eff_time_slot, it could do a findall
and take the maximum of the eval_time_expr.

For speed up you could use tabling of eff_time_slot. The whole
above works as long as the event dependencies form a DAG.

Bye